# Javascript:: Find differences between array that contains duplicated values to a unique array of that array

Tags: javascript, arrays, loops

I found many posts on stack overflow about that similar subject but none of them solve this issue here.

```
<script>

//Array GanginaA contains duplicated values.
//Array GanginaB contains only unique values that have been fetched from GanginaA

GanginaA=[0,1,2,3,4,5,5,6,7,8,9,9];
GanginaB=[0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9];

var hezi=<!--The Magic Goes Here-->

console.log(hezi);

/*
 * Expected Output:
 * 5,9
*/

</script>
```

GanginaA will always be longer or identical to GanginaB so there is no reason to calculate by the value of the longer array length.

GanginaB will always contains unique values that taken from GanginaA so it will always be the shorter array length or identical to GanginaA array.

Now it makes it a lot easier to find doubles.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use filter to get the elements like below

```
GanginaA = [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 9];
GanginaB = [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9];
var hezi = GanginaB.filter(function (item, index) {
    return GanginaA.indexOf(item) !== GanginaA.lastIndexOf(item)
});
console.log(hezi.join(" , ")); //  5, 9
```

Answer (score 2):

the easier I can think of :

```
var hezi=[];

for (var i=0;i<GanginaA.length;i++){
   hezi[GanginaA[i]] = GanginaA[i];
   hezi[GanginaB[i]] = GanginaB[i];
}
hezi = hezi.filter (function(el){return el!=undefined;});
```

does everything in O(n) actions and not O(n^2)

Answer (score 1):

Javascript's objects have hashmap like behaviour, so you can use them kind of like a set. If you iterate over all the values and set them to be keys within an object, you can use the [`Object.keys`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/keys) method to get an array of unique values out.

```
function uniqueValues() {
  var unique = {};

  [].forEach.call(arguments, function(array) {
    array.forEach(function(value) {
      unique[value] = true;
    });
  });

  return Object.keys(unique);
};
```

This function will return the unique elements in any number of arrays, passed as arguments.

```
uniqueValues([1, 2, 3], [ 1, 1, 1], [2, 2, 2], [3, 3, 3]); // [ 1, 2 3 ]
```

One drawback to this method is that Javascript coerces all keys to strings, you can turn them back into numbers by changing the return statement to:

```
return Object.keys(unique).map(Number);
```